# The animation of the character isnt playing when using play montage node in UE5

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I have a problem in ue5 using the play montage node. The montage of the character swinging is good and everything, but when i use the play animation node the montage of that specific animation works, but when using the play montage  node it doesnt. (im using animation blueprint for the character)

[this is a screenshot of the player blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cD9S.png)

[this is the tool blueprint that im using to play specific motage depending of the tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqQ6W.png)

I tried everything about the node but i dont get anywhere that is why im asking you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Montages are a way for code/BP to control the animation asset directly (unlike Animation Sequences for instance). You need a default slot in your Animation Blueprint's AnimGraph to be able to play the montage:

[image]